# How to FastCGI in C?

Tags: c, apache, cgi, fastcgi

I have a website where each webpage is compiled into a binary (I have 100 webpages, therefore I have 100 binaries). Apache's .htaccess contains the line "SetHandler cgi-script" which instructs apache to use CGI when a binary (webpage) is requested.

How can I modify this website to use FastCGI instead of CGI ?

Do I just have to include this header and use this while loop ([FastCGI.com](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-devel-kit.htm)) in each of the 100 binaries and modify .htaccess to "SetHandler fastcgi-script" ?

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h" // instead of stdio.h  
while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
```

So how will FastCGI work exactly ? Apache will dispatch webpages using 1 persistent process for the entire website or will there be 1 persistent process for each of the 100 binaries ?

Comment: I am guilty of the +1, I've always wanted to hear about CGI in C.

Comment: *pity pity pity* (Instead of 100 binaries, consider a usable web framework of sorts :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FastCGI script is a network server that listens for connections in a loop. The web server forward requests to the FCGI server which sends back some dynamically generated content - all over a socket connection. Thus a FCGI script is faster than CGI as it is not re-spawned for each request.

I don't understand why you need 100 binaries for 100 pages. A single script is enough to generate content for 100 pages, based on some request parameter. The FCGI server should also scale pretty well for multiple connections as it is usually made to poll on the socket file descriptor. (Look at the code of the implementation to make sure of this).

To generate 100 pages you don't necessarily need 100 if statements. Consider this pseudo-code:

```
hash_table page_generators; // map page types to function objects (or function pointers)
page_generators["login_page"] = handle_login_page_fn; 
page_generators["contact_page"] = handle_contact_page_fn; 
// ... and so on

// request handler
page_type = request.get("page_type");
fn = page_generators[page_type];
if (fn == NULL)
    return "<html><body>Invalid request</body></html>";
else
    return fn(request);
```

Comment: No need for 100 binaries ? How would you do it then ? A single binary with 100 if conditions like this ? if(strstr(getenv("REQUEST_URI"), "page-name")){...}elseif... Also, a single binary would be very big.

Comment: @bobby: Not as big as 100 binaries. The startup cost and boilerplate alone in all those binaries is far more expensive than a few if statements. If you want to get fancy why not put the available requests into the C equivalent of a map structure, I am certain the lookup of the current request alone in that is cheaper than hitting disk to locate the correct binary.

Comment: @bobby On how to avoid a 100 `if` statements, see the updated answer.